# Problem installing TP-Link TX201 2.5 Gigabit PCIe Network Adapter

Tags: networking, 20.04, ubuntu-drivers, support

I'm having issues switching my network connection from the onboard controller to a new TP-Link TX201 2.5 Gigabit PCIe Network Adapter.  Can someone please help me with this issue that has got this controller working in Ubuntu Server 20.04?

The card is currently showing network UNCLAIMED.  My goal is to convert the settings from my existing controller and switch them to the new controller, then change the cable to the new network controller.

Here is all the information on the system:

```
command: lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

```
uname -r 
5.4.0-146-generic
```

```
command: sudo lshw -C network 

  *-network UNCLAIMED 
       description: Ethernet controller 
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller 
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0 
       version: 04 
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list 
       configuration: latency=0 
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7000000-f700ffff memory:f7010000-f7013fff 
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 00
       serial: d8:9e:f3:17:4c:ec
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=192.168.2.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:128 memory:f7300000-f731ffff
```

```
command: cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml:   (This is from my current card that is working, not the new one)

network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s31f6:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.2.100/24
            gateway4: 192.168.2.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 8.8.4.4
                - 192.168.2.1
    version: 2
```

```
command: lspci -k
>00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
        Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Dell HD Graphics 630
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
        Subsystem: Dell 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
        Subsystem: Dell 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
        Subsystem: Dell 200 Series PCH Serial IO I2C Controller
        Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
        Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
        Subsystem: Dell 200 Series PCH CSME HECI
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
        Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode]
        Subsystem: Dell SATA Controller [RAID mode]
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH LPC Controller (Q270)
        Subsystem: Dell 200 Series PCH LPC Controller (Q270)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
        Subsystem: Dell 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
        Subsystem: Dell 200 Series PCH HD Audio
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
        Subsystem: Dell 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
        Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
        Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
        Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
        Kernel modules: e1000e
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde PRO / Venus LE / Tropo PRO-L [Radeon HD 8830M / R7 250 / R7 M465X] (rev 87)
        Subsystem: Dell Cape Verde PRO / Venus LE / Tropo PRO-L [Radeon HD 8830M / R7 250 / R7 M465X]
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]
        Subsystem: Dell Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
        Kernel driver in use: nvme
        Kernel modules: nvme
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Silly question, but have you [installed the necessary driver](https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/tx201/) for that device?

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`, `dmesg | grep -i r8169`, and `lsmod | grep -i r8169`.

Answer (score 1):

I found my pebcak issue was the driver wasn't installed.   I was able to fix my issue, thanks anyway.

Comment: I thought it might be such but didn’t want to jump to any conclusions just yet. Glad you got it sorted.